# AngularJS/Bootstrap - Select row and open details in modal with button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using AngularJS, Bootstrap, and data-toggle to open a modal. I want to click on a row in a table, get the index number and store it, and click a button to open a modal that displays more details for that row using the stored index.

My code right now can get the index of the clicked row and my button opens a modal, but they're not connected so that the button grabs the row index and shows those details in the modal. My modal shows all row data instead of the details for the one clicked row. How can I connect the clicked row to the button and how do I get my modal to show details for one app instead of all apps? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5r5rxkz/).

Here is the code snippet for the click functions:

```
$scope.selectedRow = null;

$scope.clickRow = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
    console.log(index);
};

$scope.getDetails = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
    console.log(index);
};
```

And here is the code for my table and modal that call the click functions:

```
<div id="tableDiv">
    <table id="myTable" class="table display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in head" value="{{th.id}}" class="{{th.class}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:search" ng-click="clickRow($index)" ng-class="{selected: $index === selectedRow}">
                <td>{{app.appName}}</td>
                <td>{{app.dateCreated}}</td>
                <td>{{app.dateUpdated}}</td>
                <td>{{app.payload}}</td>
                <td>{{app.status.name}}</td>
                <td>{{app.errorCode.name}}</td>
                <td>{{app.errorDesc}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in head" value="{{th.id}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="getDetails($index)">Launch</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table display">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in details" value="{{th.id}}"
                                    class="{{th.class}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
                                <td>{{app.appName}}</td>
                                <td>{{app.errorDesc}}</td>
                                <td>{{app.recordCount}}</td>
                                <td>{{app.recordFail}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work. It also doesn't match up to the code snippet you posted. Which one do you want help with?

Comment: @HankScorpio oops, didn't realize I pasted the wrong link. Updated and fixed! I am stuck on the JS code, I only provided the HTML code for quick reference.

Comment: That makes more sense. Are you aware that there are angular directives for bootstrap? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'll point out is that you're not actually using angular-ui-bootstrap, you're using the jQuery version without angular directives, and by doing so making life harder for yourself. If you're going to do much more with this or making more modals I recommend switching.

You can still make this work though.

Instead of passing the $index in `clickRow($index)`, pass the `app` itself `clickRow(app)` and assign that to your scope property.
It's a variable created in your ng-repeat loop that can be accessed by other expressions in the loop.

```
$scope.clickRow = function(app) {
  $scope.selectedApp = app
};
```

Then, in your modal's html, you can bind to the properties of `selectedApp`. It should only show you the data for that one app.